# How to measure and debug initial render response perfomance of a nuxt 3 app?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I am having 3s on the initial response from the server and I want to check which part is responsible for the high load time. An empty nuxt 3 app has a response time of less than 100ms. So obviously something with my code is terribly wrong.

Things I tried:

`DEBUG=1 yarn dev`: The information displayed did not help me to find the problem. And it's also in a dev environment only. Unfortunately, `DEBUG=1` doesn't work for `yarn preview`.

`npx nuxi analyze`: This helps only to know the size of the packages, but gives no information about how slow/fast something loads.